# Window creation fail in GLFW

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, glfw

I am having a really hard time figuring out what is wrong with my code and I can't find anything.

If I run this everything works fine and a window is created:

```
int main()
{
   GLFWwindow* win=glfwCreateWindow(640,480,"Window, NULL, NULL);
if(!win)
 std::cerr << "Failed to create a window" << std::endl;
}
```

But when I run it through a window class I created it doesn't:

main.cpp:

```
int main()

{
Window win(640, 480, "Window");
//etc...

}
```

Window.h:

```
class Window

{
public:
    Window();
    Window(int x, int y, std::string t);
    Window(Vector2i xy, std::string t);

    //...

private:

    Vector2i size;
    std::string title;
    GLFWwindow*win;

    void create();
};
```

Window.cpp:

```
Window::Window(int x, int y, std::string t)
    :size(x, y), title(t), win(nullptr)
{
    create();
}

    void Window::create()

    {
        win=glfwCreateWindow(size.x, size.y, "hello", NULL, NULL);
        if (!win)
            std::cerr << "Failed to create a window" << std::endl;
        //...
    }

//...etc
```

The window creation returns NULL and the error log is printed...
What on earth is going on?

Comment: You are missing glfwInit();

Comment: Argh.... I'm an idiot. Thanks...

Comment: Weren't you missing that in the first place? Does adding it really make the error log go away?

Comment: Any reason you aren't [setting an error callback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#error_handling)?